# Find reduced row echelon form of a matrix (not all entries are given)

Tags: matrices

Let $A\in M_{3\times4}(\mathbb{R})$ is a matrix and $b_1=(1,1,1,0),b_2=(-2,-1,0,1)$ are column vectors that are solutions to linear system $Ax=0$ and form a basis. Find $rref(A)$.

Two vectors form a basis, and we know that $dim(A)=2$.

Remaining column is non-pivot columns. How to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the reduced row echelon form of $A$.$\;A$ has row-rank=column-rank=$2$. So $R$ has a row full of zeroes (as number of non-zero rows of $R$=row-rank of $A$). So
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&a&b\\
0&1&c&d\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now as $R$ can be obtained from $A$ via left-multiplication with elementary matrices which are invertible, $R=EA$ where $E$ is invertible and hence $Ax=\vec 0\iff Rx=\vec 0$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&a&b\\
0&1&c&d\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\implies a=c=-1\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1&b\\
0&1&-1&d\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2\\-1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\implies b=2, d=1
$$

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to the homogeneous linear system $Ax=0$ form the kernel (a.k.a. nullspace) of $A$. A basis for the kernel of a matrix can be read directly from its row-reduced echelon form. In this case, the kernel is two-dimensional, so $A$ has rank $2$ and its row-reduced echelon form will be of the form $$
R=\pmatrix{1&0&a&c\\0&1&b&d\\0&0&0&0}.
$$ A basis for the kernel can be be formed by examining the columns which don’t have leading entries (pivots), in this case the third and fourth. For each of these columns, set the entry corresponding to the column number to $1$ and the other entries that correspond to rows without pivots to $0$. The rest of the entries of that basis vector are filled in with the negation of the entries of the corresponding columns from rows that *do* have pivots. For this matrix, this results in the vectors $(-a, -b, 1, 0)^T$ and $(-c, -d, 0, 1)$. Happily, these match the two given basis vectors, so we can immediately fill in the missing entries.

Note that this method of finding a basis for the kernel of a (rref) matrix is simply a short-cut to solving a set of equations for the dependent components of the basis vectors. For example, in principle you’d set the first basis vector $v_1$ to $(x,y,1,0)^T$, then solve for $x$ and $y$ in $Rv_1=0$ (or $Av_1=0$, but the former is a little less work), but this just yields the equations $x-a=0$ and $y-b=0$. Similarly for the other elements of the kernel basis.